# PhpStorm auto include used PHP files

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want PhpStorm to auto-include (`include_once`) PHP files that I use in my respective `.php` file.

Simple example: `MyTestClass.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Test;

class MyTestClass
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

When I use this class in my `index.php` file, only the namespace is auto inserted:

```
<?php

use Test\MyTestClass;

$test = new MyTestClass();
$test->sayHello();
```

But this does not work in PHP. I've to include the PHP file that contains the class:

```
<?php

include_once('./namesapce.php');

use Test\MyTestClass;

$test = new MyTestClass();
$test->sayHello();
```

Is it possible that PhpStorm inserts these files automatically with the help of `include_once`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. PhpStorm cannot do that.

And it's extremely unlikely to be implemented.

The reason is simple: it's 2022 now and PHP has class autoloading functionality for many years (since PHP 5 which is 2004):

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

---

BTW: you can use **Composer** autoloader for this purpose. It's fast and easy to use.

Are you using custom libraries or frameworks? If yes then quite likely you have it installed using Composer already. It's a standard tool these days for installing PHP packages (managing your dependencies) and classes autoloading.

You just need to tell where to find your classes in `composer.json` file and require_once the actual autoloader.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: I do not currently use any libraries. Is it still worth installing and using Composer?

Comment: Yes. It's a standard tool these days. It will not add any issues (never did for me in my custom or Laravel-based projects). If not sure how to use -- find any popular (or just any modern one) PHP library or framework on GitHub and see how they use it: `composer.json` (and check the `index.php` if it's framework -- libraries assume that your own code will have autoloader in use already). Or just look for some tutorials: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649. It's easy to use -- you just need to see and try it on a simple code first.